# Change Element inside element with Onclick or Hover property

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint-2010

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #container {position:relative;left:15%;}
      #myImage {width:65%;height:280px;}
      #text {padding-top: 50px;}
      #textbox {width:65%;height:280px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container" onclick="changeImage()" >
      <img id="myImage" src="C:\Documents and Settings\svarghe1\My Documents\Downloads\Jaguar_Xj_Saloon_4.jpgj_.jpg" alt="">
      <div id="textbox">
        <p style="color:white;text-align:center;margin-top:50px;"class="text">Jaguar_Xj_Saloon</p>

        <script>
          function changeImage() {
            if (document.getElelmentById("container").innerHTML="myImage") {
              container.appendChild(myImage)
            } else {
              container.appendChild(textbox)
            }
          }
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here, I am trying to create a script for Sharepoint site page to change an element in `div` from `Image` to `textbox` with `Onclick` or `hover` property. There might be a lot of mistakes as this is my first attempt on *JS*. I have also tried

```
<script> 
function changeImage() {
    var image= document.getElementById("myImage");
    if (image=true) {
       var element = document.getElementById("container");
       var UImage = document.createElementById("myImage");
       element.appendChild(UImage)
    } else {
       var element = document.getElementById("container");
       var Utextbox = document.createElementById("textbox");
       element.appendChild(UImage)
       element.appendChild(Utextbox);
    }
}
</script>


#container:hover #myImage{ display:none; }
```

I have tried the code above in *CSS*, instead of script. It didn't work. At the same time the code,

```
a:hover #box{ text-decoration: none;color:green;background-color: Turquoise;cursor:pointer }
```

Works really fine. Why is that? I have given `class` instead of `id`. It also didn't work. It works in ordinary *HTML* file. But can't get to work in Sharepoint site.
So, can you help?

Comment: Check all your endline, you're missing a lot of point commas.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending Image and text box from the javascript, you can already write the html codes for both and do the hide/show according to your need. I think it will make things lot easier and neat.

As for the Hover property, you can attach event of hover with jquery.
You can check the following link: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: #container:hover #myImage{
 display:none;
}
I have tried the code above in css. It didn't work. At the same time the code,
a:hover #box{
   text-decoration: none;color:green;background-color: Turquoise;cursor:pointer
}
Works really fine. Why is that?
I have given "class" instead of "id". It also didn't work.